# javascript: изменить все числа в строке

Tags: javascript

Есть строка: `Я уже 1.5 года занимаюсь программированием, написал 10.25 тысяч строк кода и за это время понял: всё-таки, я ещё долго буду просить помощи на форуме.`

Нужно эту строку так переиначить, чтобы все числа (1.5 и 10.25) остались на прежних местах, но стали в 13 раз больше. То есть: `Я уже 19.5 года занимаюсь...`

Я бы рад сам попробовать, но даже не знаю, от чего отталкиваться. Полагаю, от методов RegExp и String, но на их изучение ещё 1.5 года уйдёт, а для опытного программиста - это пятиминутное дело. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Надеюсь, ты не хочешь нам втереть какую-то дичь...

Comment: Вот так, выдаёшь шедевр за шедевром, а помнят тебя за какую-то дичь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В метод [String.prototype.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) можно передать функцию:

```js
let str = 'Я уже 1.5 года занимаюсь программированием, написал 10.25 тысяч строк кода и за это время понял: всё-таки, я ещё долго буду просить помощи на форуме.';

let res = str.replace(/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g, num => 13*num)

console.log(res);
```

`/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g` - регулярное выражение, захватывающее число, за которым может следовать точка с числом. Флаг g говорит, что нужно обработать все вхождения.

Comment: js уже лямбды поддерживает? Ого..

Comment: @nick_n_a, [стрелочные функции](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: пропустит запись числа вида `.1` хотя, наверно это и непринципиально

Comment: @Sublihim, думаю, что ни к чему тут настолько усложнять.

Comment: @vp_arth, ну, в целом - да

Comment: Надеюсь, `19.5 года` никому на `19.5 лет` исправить не надо

Comment: А почему не `/\d+(\.\d+)/g`, тот же результат ведь

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, привычка, не создавать группы захвата без необходимости

Comment: @vp_arth верная привычка, молодец :)